Fetching Properties for *.iam,*ipt using Model Derivative
I want to fetch the properties of inventor files (.iam,*.ipt) by using Model Derivative APIs.
I have stored in *.ipt files on Fusion 360 hub. To fetch properties I have first translated file to svf and then tried fetching the properties but in the response I can only see
"properties": {
"Name": "Solid1",
"Appearance": "229, 31, 31"
}
No material or mass information is available.
Can anyone help me with this?I need mass and material properties for all parts, assemblies and bodies.
I have first translated the file to svf and tried fetching the properties.

Mass properties are only available at file level - or at occurrence level inside an assembly, not for solids. So make sure you select the right element: 
https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/selection-override
Material is only available if it's also exposed through an iProperty - all iProperties are extracted from the model.
If you do need such information at solid level, then you could use Design Automation to extract any information you may need.
Update:
Just uploaded and translated an ipt file and can see the Mass Properties:

If you're having issues with seeing the properties I would suggest that you double-check things in a utility like our VS Code Extension that I used as well.

Hi @Adam Nagy,
I have created a new part (CylinderD.ipt) and assinged abs placstic material and added mass as to it in iProperties pannel.
Now I have stored it in Fusion hub and tried fetching properties by using Model derivative after translating file to svf.
I am still not getting mass and material.
